# How to play Farmville on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

I am new with Ubuntu and I have this problem: I would like to play Farmville on Facebook and it says I need to upgrade my flash player.

I have tried doing everything I found on Google related to this but nothing works. It says I have the latest version of flash player but still it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: try pipelight it will work in firefox browser https://launchpad.net/pipelight

Comment: It works in Google Chrome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Chrome downloaded from [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/).

> Renato, you can still play on linux. All you need is the chrome browser from https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/. This version (in contrast to the default chromium browser that comes in the repositories of your version of linux) does not use Adobe flash but instead uses pepper flash player which still works with FV2.

Quote from [here](https://zyngablog.typepad.com/farmville_2/2014/05/flash-115-upgrade.html#comment-6a01156fcaccc3970c01a511be2515970c).

Comment: Thanks. Now I can open FV2 but I can't play in full screen. It doesn't evan show me the full screen button